# Javascript array with custom properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing, properties

I have started using a techique for indexing arrays by adding a key property to the array. This is useful if you wish to preserve the order of an array but also do quick lookups on it (especially when getting data sets from JSON). The advantage of the the individual key properties is that they are a reference back to the original item in the array saving on memory.

Can anyone think of any memory/implications for this technique? Already I am running into minor issues such as:

- Qunit cannot test for a property on array as it expects an array type,
- jQuery extend won't copy the key property when copying an arrray.

These aside this seems the nicest way to index an array while mainting its order.

```
var keyArray = function(arrayToKey,property){
        if (typeof arrayToKey !== 'undefined') {
            arrayToKey.key = {};
            var l = arrayToKey.length,
                i = 0;
            if (typeof property !== 'undefined') {
                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    if (arrayToKey[i] !== null) {
                        arrayToKey.key[arrayToKey[i][property]] = arrayToKey[i];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    if (arrayToKey[i] !== null) {
                        arrayToKey.key[arrayToKey[i]] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    };
```

This takes an array and either: keys it on the content of each array item, or if a property name is passed in it keys it on the property of each object in the array e.g.

```
Example 1:
keyArray(['hello','nice','world']);
-> 
['hello',' ','world'].key{
    hello: true,
    nice, true,
    world, true
};
Example 2:
keyArray([
    {
        name: 'hello',
        value: 'hello value'
    },
    {
        name: 'nice',
        value: '  value'
    },
    {
        name: 'world',
        value: 'world value'
    }
]);
->
[
    {
        name: 'hello',
        value: 'hello value'
    },
    {
        name: 'nice',
        value: '  value'
    },
    {
        name: 'world',
        value: 'world value'
    }
].key{
    hello: {
        name: 'hello',
        value: 'hello value'
    },
    nice: {
        name: 'nice',
        value: 'nice value'
    },
    world: {
        name: 'world',
        value: 'world value'
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't understand the value of this. In example #1, you'd be better off just using an object in the first place. The key seems to add no value, since it doesn't have any ordinal information. In example #2, the key creates a copy of the entire array. This seems counter to your goal of saving memory. If you want a way to do a fast look up an array value, then why not create an object that's actually just a cross reference to the array index? e.g. for ex. 2 `{name: 'hello', value: 0 }`

Comment: Cheers Jamietre. In the second case, the keyed array IS a reference to the original array not a copy (it just appears that in the way it is output). The reason for wanting to do this is to keep a copy of the array hash as part of the array object which can then be easily passed around. On a current project I am working on the order of items is of critical importance, but we also have to do lots of cross-referencing between array data sets, and hash keys are the easiest way. You have highlighted the possibitlity of having a hash object with one property for the order of the original array.